# How to add class to multiple view-blocks using twig?

Tags: views, theming, blocks, css-js-aggregation

I have four blocks to a view. I want to add class 'fancy-body' to all four blocks. How can I add that.

**view_id** : categories

**display_id's** of blocks : block_1, block_2, block_3, block_4

I know, I can add classes by creating individual twig template file for each block. like this,

```
block--views-block--categories-block-1.html.twig
block--views-block--categories-block-2.html.twig
block--views-block--categories-block-3.html.twig
block--views-block--categories-block-4.html.twig
```

Is it possible to achieve in single twig template file? How can I achieve that?

Need Help, Thank You!

Comment: What if you add the class to all the block displays in the view manually in Advanced section? Are you going to create a twig file simply to add classes?

Comment: I want to manipulate the structure of all the blocks of a particular view.

Comment: Ok. Then you will need to create a twig file to modify HTML structure. Please modify your question, as it indicates only to add a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's just classes you need, the modules mentioned in Joseph's answer should be enough.

If you need to make more alterations and definitely need a custom template file, you can implement [`hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK/9.2.x).

Something like:

```
function module_theme_suggestions_block(array $variables) {
  $suggestions = [];

  if ($variables['elements']['#base_plugin_id'] == 'views_block') {
    if (preg_match('/views_block:categories-block_[0-9]+/', $variables['elements']['#plugin_id'])) {
      $suggestions[] = 'block__views_block__categories_all_blocks';
    }
  }

  return $suggestions;
}
```

With the above example your single template file would be named `block--views-block--categories-all-blocks.html.twig`.

Comment: what should be the function name, if module name is "XYZ",  Is `XYZ_theme_suggestions_block()` right?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: the  classes and id's that are added in `block--views-block--categories-all-blocks.html.twig` are reflecting in drupal site. can you tell me where exactly, In what file or In what folder I need to add that code. I added that file in `XYZ.module`  file. thannk you !

Comment: Is everything should be same or need to be changed? like what is `#base_plugin_id` and `#plugin_id`

Comment: You shouldn't need to change anything, it matches the view id and display id from the template files in the question

Answer (score 2):

There are several modules that allow you to add classes to blocks via admin, depending on where you're adding the blocks:

- If using Layout Builder: https://www.drupal.org/project/layout_builder_component_attributes

> The Layout Builder Component Attributes module allows editors to add
> HTML attributes to Layout Builder components (blocks). Attributes can
> be added to 1) the block (outer) element, 2) the block title, and 3)
> the block content (inner) element.

- If using Block Layout: https://www.drupal.org/project/block_classes

> Block Classes allows users to add classes to block title, content, and
> wrapper of any block through the block's configuration interface. This
> module extends the Block Class module features.